Il n'y comprend rien
Why is there an expression “Il n'y comprend rien”? Normally, aren't we supposed to say comprendre qqch directly? Isn't "y" usually used to replace à qqch?

It does, the pronoun y replaces what he doesn't understand anything about (ne rien comprendre à quelque chose).
Il ne comprend rien. He doesn't understand anything.
Il n'y comprend rien. He doesn't understand anything about it.
A bit of etymology might help understanding what this rien is.
In Latin rēs means 'thing', its accusative rem gave the French rien which originally meant "(some)thing".
An hypothetical old French sentence might have read:

Il comprend rien literally meaning "Il comprend (quelque) chose"1.

Its negation is made by adding ne leading to:

Il ne comprend rien literally meaning "Il ne comprend pas chose".

Because rien was so often used in negative sentences, it started to acquire a "negative polarity" so while un rien still means 'something', rien alone ends up to mean 'nothing'.
Back to your sentences:

Il ne comprend rien kind of means Il ne comprend pas "(quelque) chose", i.e. 'He doesn't understand (any)thing'.

Il n'y comprend rien means Il ne comprend pas "(quelque) chose" à ça, i.e. 'He doesn't understand (any)thing about it.


Both of these examples show that comprendre is used a transitive way and that a ça / y are not relevant to the verb but to its object, rien.
1 In modern French, il comprend rien means exactly the opposite, i.e. 'he understands nothing', as ne is no longer an obligatory negation marker outside a formal context.

I feel sudden pangs of doubt. Il entrave que pouic or il en trave que pouic?

@FrançoisJurain Y bite que tchi.


It's because of this: comprendre can have rien after it and then a phrase with à/aux/au  [noun] or it can have a relative clause. So there are in effect two things. For example:
Je ne comprends pas le français. I don't understand French. Direct object. Not followed by anything.

OK, but:



Je ne comprends rien au sens de la phrase.
rien calls for y there.
I don't understand anything about the meaning of the sentence becomes:




Je n'y comprends rien. I don't understand [anything about] it. Direct object or phrasal verb in English.




Je ne comprends pas ce que tu dis. [clause]
I don't understand what you are saying.
Becomes: Je n'y comprends rien.
I don't understand anything you are saying OR say.




But it's very often the à that induces the y (as opposed to its "cousin" de becoming en, no example given of that here) :
Pour participer à la politique, il faut comprendre des situations complexes.
Pour y participer, il faut comprendre des situations compliquées.
To participate in politics, you have to understand complicated situations.


We never say à les in French.

I fixed it now...an oversight., which is weird for me since I would never say it...

Are there really "two things" here?

@Frank There are two different things. A noun or noun phrase versus a clause.

@Lambie I'm afraid that still incorrect. How can ne pas comprendre be followed by à, aux, au? You seems to be confusing pas and rien.

@jlliagre Satisfied now? I am not confusing anything at all. It was just sloppy. And I think my answer is more comprehensive than yours, in any case.

Comment are there to point mistakes, not to satisfy anyone. Whatever comprehensive the reply, comprendre can't be followed by à, aux, au. For examples, you can’t say Je comprends au français. What can be followed by à, aux, au is quelque chose or rien here.
